# MongoDB get size of Capped collection

Tags: mongodb, capped-collections

Is it possible to get max size of capped collection in MongoDB, the same size you have specified during creation?

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/-3fmsKwb4GA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before V2.6, you can get it by

```
db.system.namespaces.findOne({name : namespace}).options.size;
// namesapce : <db>.<collection>
```

For V2.6+ (I test on V2.6.4), you can only get integral multiples of EXTENT_SIZE.

```
returnSize = Math.ceil(specifiedSize / EXTENT_SIZE) * EXTENT_SIZE
// for example, returnsize = Math.ceil(1 / 4096) * 4096 = 4096
```

Answer (score 3):

db.collectioname.stats()

will give you the max size. It will always be in multiple of 256

```
> db.createCollection( "log_cap2", { capped: true, size: 7500 } )
```

{ "ok" : 1 }
>

> db.log_cap2.stats()
>   {
>           "ns" : "test.log_cap2",
>           "size" : 0,
>           "count" : 0,
>           "storageSize" : 4096,
>           "capped" : true,
>           "max" : -1,
>           "maxSize" : 7680,

Even thou I gave size as 7500  it will allocate in multiples of 256

256*29 = 7424
256*30=7680